# How to get the top n values from dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe read from csv file, and it's pretty much like a score table, and it has 4 columns

```
school_name class_name, student_name, score
```

What I want to do is group the school and class, and see the top 3 scores in each of the classes, and I'm trying it in this way

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("sep", ",")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("students.csv")

df.groupBy("school_name", "class_name")....
```

And, I'm just stuck here.

Any advice?

**EDIT**
It's not the top 3 scores but top 3 scores in each of the classes.

Comment: `df.groupBy("school_name", "class_name").agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum("score").desc).show(3)` is all you need.

Comment: Thanks!  I just updated my description.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan there should be a dupe for this somewhere

Comment: yes may be @eliasah ;)

Comment: @Bomin then you would need to go with Window function to give ranks and filter the top three in each group. :)